# WordPress URl and Digg Digg

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website with temporary url as `www.mydomain.com/newsite/#/`. Then I plugged Digg Digg plugin for sharing through social networks. My original post resides in

```
http://www.mydomain.com/newsite/#/22/post/1/hello-world
```

However, whenever I pressed the Facebook like button I notice that the liked URL  is shown as below on my Facebook activity log.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/newsite/index.php/hello-world/
```

**UPDATE**

Clicking the above URL only direct me to a page where I can see all the  comments posted but not the posted news itself

What could possible cause this issue ? I am using Osaka Template.

Comment: kindly check your facebok url is that placed correctly ?

Comment: yes. I have updated my question too.

Comment: Perhaps you might have more success asking on wordpress.stackexchange.com. I would migrate the question for you but I don't think I have the rep to.